# Why is the margin for my footer not being displayed? [CSS]

Tags: css, margin, footer

This is a fairly basic HTML/CSS question, and I'm sorry I'm having to ask this here (I searched my best!). I've written the following HTML and CSS code, and while the header section is separated by a neat 20 pixels from the article and aside sections, the footer is being separated by only 10 px. In fact, irrespective of the margin I set for the footer, the separation remains 10px. What am I doing wrong?

It would be amazing if you could test this code out in a browser to see what I mean. I'm also inserting a link to a picture below of the skewed margins between the article / aside section and the footer section.

http://cl.ly/image/3M2u1L0x2C0x

**HTML Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>My Grey Boxes</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <header></header>
    <article></article>
    <aside></aside>
    <footer></footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS Code**

```
#wrapper {
    margin: auto;
    width: 940px;
    }

body {
    background-color: #fafafa;
    }

header {
    height: 120px;
    width: 920px;
    display: block;
    margin: 10px 10px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #c6c6c6;
    }

article {
    height: 740px;
    width: 600px;
    margin: 10px 10px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #c6c6c6;
    }

/* Keep scrolling! */

aside {
    height: 740px;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 10px 10px;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #c6c6c6;
    }

footer {
    height: 120px;
    width: 920px;
    display: block;
    margin: 10px 10px; /* Why is this being ignored? */
    background-color: #c6c6c6;
    position: relative;
    clear: both;
    }
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated! I'm sorry if I'm not following all the community guidelines here - this is my first time posting on StackOverflow, and I'll pick things up soon! Thanks ahead! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear the floats **before** you get to the footer. Changing your HTML to this will work:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <header></header>
    <article></article>
    <aside></aside>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    <footer></footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It sure worked, but I'm a bit hesitant to use it because we're adding an HTML element to fix an appearance problem. Isn't that the job of CSS? Here's a very well explained article that tries to deal with it using the overflow:hidden CSS property (in addition to a couple of other methods): http://bit.ly/YcXFNG; I however couldn't get to apply it to my document. Would it be possible for you to look into that? I'm just getting started with CSS, and I really, really appreciate your help! Thank you so much for your patience! :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! I did some research, and finally found these articles that explained 3 different ways to achieve this (one that you suggested, and two others using CSS).

1. CSS Floats 101: http://alistapart.com/article/css-floats-101
2. Clearing floats with CSS: http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html
3. Clearing floats with overflow:auto or overflow:hidden: http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2005/03/clearing_floats.html

Comment: It's pretty usual for elements to be used purely for this purpose. Feel free to accept my answer by clicking on the "tick" :)